# What information leaks to a site that I am hotlinking images from?

Tags: browser, http, html

Suppose I have two websites: website A and website B. Website A hotlinks to images on website B. What information will visitors to website A be sending to website B?

In particular, I would like to know which headers the user browser sends to website B when rendering website A.

Comment: I would say that it depends on the browser... I would not expect lynx or links to send the same information that Chrome sends.

Comment: @SergeBallesta Yes it does depend on the browser. However, most browsers are not customized and will follow the spec.

Answer (score 0):

The browser will typically include the [referer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referer) (note the spelling) in the headers of the request to Website B to fetch the image.  This referer would typically be the URL of the referring page, so in this case, the URL of the page served from Website A, which hotlinks to the image on Website B.

However, Website A can specify a [referrerpolicy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#attr-referrerpolicy) in the `<img>` tag, which can be used to tell the browser (at least, for most modern browsers) to omit the referer from headers of the request to Website B to fetch the image.